# Do not remove trailing spaces in inline code

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, code-formatting, markdown, markdown-rendering

If I write

```
`    a    b    c    `
```

Markdown renders it as

`a    b    c`

Inline code should not be trimmed. It's still code, and the spaces can be relevant.

---

Example:

> [...] so `.2` and `.3` are invalid CSS selectors. You can escape them as `.\32` and `.\33`.

The space after the escaped digit can't always be omitted, so hiding it is bad.

---

Some people are arguing that trimming spaces helps in poorly formatted posts. Well, IMO that's not a good reason. Poorly formatted posts look like this:

> enter code here
>      `foo     bar`
>     `enter code here` Do you haz teh codez?

With my proposal it will become like this:

> enter code here
>      `foo     bar`    
>     `enter code here` Do you haz teh codez?

Really, not much different. Poorly formatted posts remain poorly formatted after trimming spaces. And even if in some rare cases trimming spaces improves the formatting considerably, so what? Just because some people are too lazy to format in a coherent way, I must switch to HTML syntax instead of the more convenient markdown?

This is a programming site, and code is important. StackOverflow shouldn't alter my code. Trimming spaces alters my code.

---

It's worth noting that [several markdown implementations](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=%60%20%20%20%20a%20%20%20%20b%20%20%20%20c%20%20%20%20%60) already behave like this:

• marked 0.2.6
• kramdown 1.2.0
• cebe/markdown MarkdownExtra 1.1.0
• cebe/markdown GFM 1.1.0
• cebe/markdown 1.1.0
• Maruku (Math-Enabled) 0.7.3.beta1
• Maruku 0.7.2
• Gambas 3.8.90
• RDiscount 2.1.7
• lunamark 0.4.0

Comment: Just tested a few ideas -  neither escaping a space with a backslash nor copying-and-pasting an `nbsp` from elsewhere works. (Had to copy/paste because my iPad doesn't provide a non-breaking-space in its standard keyboard. So, *cave canem*, it could be it just didn't survive the clipboard.)

Comment: But what with those who don't bother trimming unnecessary whitespaces from their code (Indentation for example)?

Comment: @AlonEitan Then their code will already be bad formatted. So this change won't matter. Downvote these posts and move on, or edit to fix.

Comment: @Oriol Ok, sound good

Comment: @RadLexus Non-breaking spaces are not trimmed for me, at least in the preview. Sometimes they are converted to normal spaces when copying or pasting.

Comment: I faced the same issue a while ago and couldn't get it working, was about to delete my answer until I realized that `<code>` tags work. Don't know if this is often an issue, but it is really annoying when facing it first.

Comment: Have you checked what the Markdown spec says about this?

Comment: @jpmc26 Nope. But I think SO implementation is already not compliant anyways.

Comment: @jpmc26 OK, [commonmark](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.25/#code-spans) says "*The contents of the code span are the characters between the two backtick strings, with leading and trailing spaces and line endings removed, and whitespace collapsed to single spaces.*". StackOverflow does not respect the later, so I guess it could also ignore the former :P

Comment: Try posting your [Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)) programming issue :)

Comment: @Oriol Our new CommonMark implementation currently being used for Documentation *does* respect all those rules, and will eventually be pushed out to Q&A as well.

Comment: @animuson Why is it status-declined if it's something that is going to be fixed?

Comment: @Rob Because the request is to do the opposite. They don't want the spaces to be trimmed. The spaces will continue to be trimmed. In fact, *more* white-space collapsing will be done in the future.

Comment: @animuson Sorry - I misread the comment thread, my bad

Answer (score 13):

This behavior is *required* by the original Markdown [rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code):

> The backtick delimiters surrounding a code span may include spaces — one after the opening, one before the closing. This allows you to place literal backtick characters at the beginning or end of a code span:
>
> ```
> A single backtick in a code span: `` ` ``
>
> A backtick-delimited string in a code span: `` `foo` ``
> ```
>
> will produce:
>
> ```
> <p>A single backtick in a code span: <code>`</code></p>
>
> <p>A backtick-delimited string in a code span: <code>`foo`</code></p>
> ```

Clearly, in those examples, the spaces (after the opening and before the closing backticks) should not be in the output. In fact, I would go so far as to say that in most cases, those spaces are not wanted/needed. In the rare instances when you really do need to preserve the spaces, the workarounds mentioned in the other answer will suffice. People have been working with the current implementation for over a decade. I don't see any reason to change it now.

Additionally, CommonMark (which is considered an improvement/update to Markdown by its creators) not only retains the rule, but actually provides for the removal of more whitespace. As per their [rule](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.25/#code-spans):

> The contents of the code span are the characters between the two backtick strings, with leading and trailing spaces and line endings removed, and whitespace collapsed to single spaces.

Comment: Testing whether backticks work... `` ` `` Nope. SO is already noncompliant. But thanks for checking the standard. =) +1

Comment: Maybe spaces could be trimmed if the first or last non-space character is a backtick. That is, the space would be a way to escape the backtick. Otherwise don't trim.

Comment: @jpmc26: That's only in comments. Post Markdown properly handles those. (Comment Markdown is fairly irredeemable.)

Comment: Do we even care about precise compatibility with the *original* Markdown rules? [Stack Overflow leadership was making incompatible changes and calling out Markdown's creator for not improving Markdown all the way back in 2009](https://blog.codinghorror.com/responsible-open-source-code-parenting/). Jeff might not be with Stack Overflow any more, but I don't think the situation he was talking about has improved.

Comment: The standard says _one_ space should be trimmed on each side. I would be okay with that behavior.

Comment: @user2357112 the result of Jeff (and others) dissatisfaction with Markdown resulted in a new spec for CommonMark, which retains this rule. I've edited my answer to include a note about that.

Comment: @JanDvorak As noted in an edit to my answer, the more recent spec for CommonMark specifically removed all leading and trailing whitepsace, not just one space.

Comment: @Oriol, as the maintainer of a Markdown implementation, I would not want to maintain such an inconsistent behavior. The support headache would be to much. Users would be confused by the different behavior. Consistently removing the spaces for all code spans or removing none are the only two viable options. As removing spaces was chosen years ago and many thousands of existing document already rely on that behavior it makes no sense to change it now.

Answer (score 8):

Let's see if it works with   `inserting non breaking spaces`   using Special Characters. Yup. (That's on a Mac – presumably, on a Windows 'chine, one could type <kbd>Alt+160</kbd>.)

Alternative: forced recognition of HTML codes, by wrapping with `<code>` instead of backticks:  `there is one regular space before and two after`  . Yup.

Fortunately, prefix and suffix spaces are *rarely* significant, so I suppose the default behavior is okay-ish, and there are workarounds possible when absolutely necessary.

Comment: Having workarounds is nice and all, but I don't see why this can't be made easy by allowing trailing spaces.

Comment: This particular workaround is _not_ nice and all. When the casual reader tries to copy this from the screen, they will be copying nbsp's instead of real spaces.

Comment: @MrLister: I hadn't thought of that! You are absolutely right, most programming languages (all of them?) don't like non breaking spaces, not any more than stuff such as en-dashes and curly quotes. ... Addendum: but they don't survive copy/paste with Edge – also no multiple spaces.

Comment: @Oriol The second alternative works fine: just use `<code>` if you need to preserve the trailing spaces. In the same way: if you need a code block with a bold line use `<pre>` and manually add the bold using `<b>` to the offended line.  The default behaviour is fine, and in that 0.001% of cases where you need something else using HTML works so I don't see any reason to change the default behaviour.

Comment: Agreed:  a) Any new feature starts with -200 points; b) there is an acceptable workround for the few cases where it matters; c) the current behaviour has the nice behaviour that it removes trailing spaces from sloppily formatted code.  (I accept that last point is a weak argument.)

Comment: @RadLexus: not all programming languages have a problem with `nbsp`s. [Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)), for one, simply ignores them as comments...

Comment: On a Mac, I believe Option+Space makes an nbsp.

Comment: @MrLister are you sure browsers copy them as nbsp? Firefox seems to convert them to "normal" spaces at least. Anyway, I don't think we should be using workarounds for this.