# Superfluous whitespace in inline code blocks in comments

Tags: discussion, bug, code-formatting

In my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452807/cutting-specific-chunks-from-a-haskell-string/40452901#comment68151203_40452807) on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452807/cutting-specific-chunks-from-a-haskell-string/40452901) question I tried to use multiple consecutive space characters in an inline code block. However, SO trimmed every double space to single spaces.

Is this a bug or expected behaviour? Furthermore, if it is the latter, do we want to change this?

Comment: Related (although it's about posts not comments in particular): [Do not remove trailing spaces in inline code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336367/215552)